# How to align tables in a table to the next column?

Tags: css, asp.net

First, let me name the tables as it will be easy for you all to understand which table I'm referring to. Table AA is the table which contains several Table BBs. Right now, I have all the BBs in Table AA. So, whenever I generate BBs in the Table AA, each BB fills each row of Table AA. (<----So far I have code for this)http://i59.tinypic.com/2wqgxfr.jpg Basically, I need to move the tables in blue(not all) to new column.

Now, my question is, how to align BBs to the next column of Table AA if (e.g.3 rows filled with 3 tables), and I want to place the subsequent tables into the next column of Table AA till the maximum row of 3 is filled and then move the remaining to the next column and so forth.

```
str["Apps"] += "<table align=\"center\"><tr align=\"center\" style=\"outline:thin solid\"><td width=\"100px\">";


if (myAppCat.Rows.Count != 0 )

    for (int y = 0; y < myAppCat.Rows.Count; y++)

    str["Apps"] += "<table align=\"center\"><tr><td  bgcolor=\"#0099FF\" height=\"20px\" width=\"120px\" style=\"outline: thin solid\" align=\"center\">" +
                                                                   "<font align=\"center\" color=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Arial\">" + myAppCat.Rows[y]["Cat_Name"].ToString() + "</font>" +
                                                                   "</tr><tr><td height=\"4px\"></td></tr></table>";

    str["Apps"] += "</td></tr>";

    str["Apps"] += "</td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: Please provide the rendered HTML...

Comment: Hi, I have attached the url for the rendered html screenshot. I can't add the image directly here as I need 10 reputations to post an image. :(

Comment: No, post the rendered HTML *code* (View > Source)

Comment: hi, thank u so much! :) I've figured out a way to do it. I need to create a variable in a for loop to count the number of times the BB is generated in AA, then, instead of creating another column in same table(Table AA), I have created two tables with one columns each.